# Excel: Get cell value by referencing text of another cell (without using VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this situation.

A1="Text I want" (A1 is the text i want)

X1="A1" (X1 is the cell of the text i want)

I now want Z1 to be the text of A1 using the reference provided by X1.

Ex: Z1=gettextofthiscell(X1)==>getvalueofthiscell(A1)=="Text I want"

What formula for Z1 would do something like this (without using VBA)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use INDIRECT

> **[INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**

Insert this function in Z1. The argument must be X1. Of course, X1 value must be `A1`. Then the formula will read XI and get get the text of A1.

```
=INDIRECT(X1)
```

An example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for Indirect function:
Z1=Indirect(X1)